# Inconsistent Spring Data exists results with Concurrent Requests in Spring Service

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, race-condition

I'm encountering inconsistency with existsBy spring data repository method in my Spring service that exposes a REST API endpoint. The endpoint processes incoming records using the processRecords method, which includes transactional logic. However, when I send multiple concurrent requests, the behavior of the recordStatusResolver.getRecordStatus method seems to be inconsistent, resulting in incorrect statuses being returned due to concurrent read/write in db.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
@Transactional
public void processRecords(List<IncomingRecordDto> inputRecords, SomeRequest someRequest) {
    for (IncomingRecordDto inputRecord : inputRecords) {
        var sourceId = getSourceId(inputRecord);
        var status = recordStatusResolver.getRecordStatus(sourceId);
        internalRecord.setStatus(status);
        internalRecord = recordRepository.save(internalRecord);
    }
}
```

The recordStatusResolver bean has a transactional method getRecordStatus that determines the status based on existing records:

```
@Transactional
public RecordStatus getRecordStatus(String sourceId) {
    var existsRunningRecordBySourceId = recordRepository.existsBySourceIdAndStatusIsNot(sourceId, PROCESSED);
    if (existsRunningRecordBySourceId) {
        return WAITING;
    }
    return PROCESSING;
}
```

However, when I tested the service using JMeter with 100 concurrent requests, I observed that the existsBySourceIdAndStatusIsNot query sometimes returns incorrect results. In some cases, the initial queries return false, leading to a PROCESSING status being returned, even though there are already records with the same source ID being processed.

I suspect this issue is related to concurrent transactions and isolation levels, but I'm not sure how to address it. Can anyone provide insights into why this might be happening and suggest possible solutions to ensure the correct behavior of the getRecordStatus method even under high concurrency?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: `processRecords` processes a list in a single transaction, so changes are visible only after commit. Whereas the `getRecordStatus` uses 1 record. So if the first is still processing the other cannot see the change yet (which is the whole point of transactions).

Comment: Yes, that is one problem. But another one is that when there are multiple requests with single element list of records, they still can return existsBy = false.

Comment: Which is what transactions are for. Data is only visible after commit, if not committed the changes aren't visible. So the results aren't inconsistent, they are exactly as they should be, from a transactional point of view.

Comment: Will programmatic transaction management help me in this situation? Lets say I will use PlatformTransactionManager and programatically set transaction commit/rollback?

Comment: No it won't as the commit still happens on the same point in time.

Comment: But I can set commit for each record in list after saving entity, cant I?

Comment: You can but you don't need manual control for that., just delegate the update to a method that operates on a single entity and make that transactional. But keep in mind that a lot of small transactions is probably slower then 1 large transaction.